# How to use both custom eval_metric and a built-in metric in xgboost.XGBClassifier

Tags: xgboost, evaluation

Hello!

I am trying to combine a list of eval_metrics consisting of a one custom eval function and multiple built-in eval functions.

When i use a list of built-in functions everything works ok:

```py
model.fit(
    X_train_inner,
    y_train_inner,
    early_stopping_rounds=20,
    eval_metric = ["error", "logloss", "map"],
    eval_set=[(X_test_inner, y_test_inner)])
```

Also, when I use my custom function on its own, everything is OK:

```py
model.fit(
    X_train_inner,
    y_train_inner,
    early_stopping_rounds=20,
    eval_metric = custom_f1_eval_function,
    eval_set=[(X_test_inner, y_test_inner)])
```

But how do I pass both custom and builtin functions to the eval_metric parameter?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1125

```
def auc_copc(preds, dtrain):
  preds = 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-preds))
  labels = dtrain.get_label()
  auc = roc_auc_score(labels, preds)
  copc = np.sum(labels) / np.sum(preds)
  return [('auc', auc), ('copc', copc)]
```

Comment: Add some context to your response to make it more meaningful and useful. It that link changes this response becomes hard to understand.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided. See [answer].